# Google Drive access authenticated user data

Tags: google-drive-api

i have a scene where i need to access data from authenticated user's Drive. in my website i have a link to **Connect to Google Drive** once a user will click on the link we will authenticate user and access data from users drive.

> i am able to authenticate user and i have a redirect url, when it redirects it produce url i.e.

```
http://apps.example.com/demo/?code=4/ujkisZloix6a9HbXUsHvNj-Z8a0cw.4152lkoh0Jzz0RgrKXntQAax3ancbdI
```

now how to access user data ?
Please help

Answer (score 0):

You will probably use `OAuth2` to access the user's drive data.
It also depends how you access the Google Apis (Javascript, Java, etc).
In the recent Google I/O conference there were 2 talks that explains how to do it.

- [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/604/)
- [Using Google APIs from Javascript](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/gooio2012/600/)